# My circumstances have changed - I'm now unable to do on-call hours

Tags: job-change, team-role

i'm a junior IT support engineer and recently i was asked to start an on-call out of hours rotation.  our senior engineers currently do on-call duties however in my work contract it stipulates that i can be asked to work out of hours.  recently my circumstances have changed - i recently divorced and i'm a sole parent to my children, so outside 9-5pm i'm their primary carer.  reading the on-call requirements i'm unable to meet the obligations.  my manager doesn't understand my parenting duties and will not negotiate - is there anything i can do or will i have quit?

Comment: Talking to your manager is usually the way to go, but if you've tried that and it hasn't worked, it's unlikely. You could consult with a lawyer, because "asked to work out of hours occasionally" and "asked to do a regular rotation out of hours" could be different. It seems pretty harsh for your manager to force everyone to take up out of hours work suddenly regardless of their situation. I'm not sure we can really help your situation here, short of talking to your manager more.

Comment: It also depends on where you live and what the labor laws in your area are regarding the legality of this and what rights you might have.  Do you have the ability to do this work remotely (i.e. from your home)?

Comment: Say "OK, manager, I'll take the hours. You'll be able to watch my kids during that time, right?"

Comment: That is harsh.  Before you quit go to HR.  Ask if there is another job you can be assigned to?  If the answer is no then ask for a some time to find another job.

Comment: is this physical on call or just responding electronically - the later should be manageable

Answer (score 4):

There is always times where you're on call, but unable to react immediately - single parent or not. You've explained your situation to your manager, and they would like you to be on call anyways.

It might be that the on-call person rarely if ever gets called. It might be that you're likely to get called in the dead of night when your children are asleep. Or it might be that you're right and you can't supply the support necessary for the company.

I would try to do the best you can, keeping your children as your highest priority. If that means you're slow to respond, or unable to drop everything to fix a company problem then so be it. If your boss complains, you get to say "I told you so" (and maybe look for new work).

But more likely, you'll not get called or be able to juggle things.

Comment: If the children aren't old enough to take care of themselves during the afternoon if the single parent has to respond to a call, then leaving them alone in bed asleep isn't an option either.

Answer (score 2):

The wording of your contract (the one you actually signed) matters. If as you say "it stipulates that i can be asked to work out of hours" and that is all that it says, then politely decline those requests that are inconvenient for you: your contract states that you may be *asked* to work out-of-hours but places no obligation on you to say 'yes' to such requests.

Note also that working out-of-hours is not the same as on-call. Out-of-hours could just be scheduled work that is mutually agreed. On-call means you are promising to be available for work for an extended period in case of emergency.

If, however, your contract states that you may be required to be on-call outside of working hours, that is a different matter. Typically, however, that is a responsibility which comes with a lump of extra pay - some for being on-call and hourly pay (typically at a higher rate) for time when you're actually called up. If they want flexibility as well as additional work, they need to pay you for it. If they are paying you for it and you can't do it, you will need to request to drop that element from the contract and lose the pay (however the employer may argue it is essential to the contract).

It should be clear from your contract how much on-call is expected and how responsive they expect you to be (attend to an incident withn 2 hours? 30 mins?). If it isn't clear it could be that the contractual term is too vague to be enforceable - however you should check with your trade union representative (or if you don't have one, then whoever else you go to for legal questions) as this is likely to vary by jurisdiction.

Until you have taken advice, be careful about appearing to accept out-of-hours work and make it clear that any out-of-hours work you agree to is on a trial basis.

If you are asked to do out-of-hours work or on-call duties, you'll also want to make sure you are getting at least a good a deal as the senior engineers, otherwise you'll have management trying to save money by giving you work instead of the seniors, and both you and they will lose out that way.

Comment: A very reasonable answer: particularly the section pointing out that there's not necessarily an obligation to do everything asked. There's a distinct difference between asking you do to one extra evening, and demanding you move to an on-call rota.

Answer (score 1):

First off: you've signed that contract. Nothing less or more

Now a little bit nicer: Contracts can be changed when the circumstances changes. Talk to your manager about that and try to get an offer how the on call duty can be removed from your contract. I think they will give you an offer with some minor drawback regarding your loan.

Answer (score 0):

You do what every other single parent does - you manage.  You build a new support network.  Find family or friends that can help out on occasion if needed.  You'll need them anyway for lots of reasons even if you change jobs.

Talk to your co-workers.  Are there any other single parents?  How do they do it?

Comment: 'You do what every other single parent does, you manage' - I disagree, a significant number of us have bosses who understand the concepts of 'work-life balance' and 'my family comes first'... Any manager who expects an employee to put their employment over their children has, at best, a tenuous understand of employment, life, parenthood, management, and people.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere "Can be asked to work out of hours" is a very different concept to "Regularly/constantly rota'd to be on-call". And expecting someone to work their core hours plus be on-call outside of that with a family and drop everything to jump to work? I'm not saying it's a tenuous contract, I'm suggesting that the manager perhaps doesn't understand people. I regularly work outside my core hours, but there's a difference.

Comment: It does if it wasn't an original part of the responsibilities of the role and he's demanding it rather than enquiring about the possibility. Again there's a difference between me taking a role with on-call responsibilities (which I may choose not to if I'm the primary caregiver) and having them added after the fact without an opt-out